dictionary, collision and linked list
If I understand the dictionary correctly, if a collision occurs, objects with the same hash will be placed on a linked list.
How will I know that multiple objects are under one key?
How can I access all of them in that case?
I'm trying to simulate a collision, so in the code below, I return hash = 100 for each object.

Dictionary<Test, int> dict = new Dictionary<Test, int>();
dict.Add(new Test() { MyProperty = 1 }, 1);
dict.Add(new Test() { MyProperty = 2 }, 2);
dict.Add(new Test() { MyProperty = 3 }, 3);

var key = new Test() { MyProperty = 1 };
var result = dict[key];

class Test
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is Test test &&
               MyProperty == test.MyProperty;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}


"How will I know that multiple objects are under one key?" - they are not under one key, hash is not a key.

Also you should note that you can have a "collision" even if you have different hashes - dictionary will not allocate the array for all possible values of int, it will allocate some size (based on prime number) and do something like var actualHash = calculatedHash % currentSizeOfDict (maybe something smarter but in the nutshell idea is somewhat like that).


How will I know that multiple objects are under one key?
How can I
access all of them in that case?

They will not be under the same key, but rather in the same "bucket" in the internal array managed by the Dictionary.
A stadard .NET Dictionary supports only one element per unique key.
You can still access the various elements given their unique key, as shown below:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj) { return obj is Test test && MyProperty == test.MyProperty; }

    public override int GetHashCode() { return 100; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create the dictionary:
        Dictionary<Test, int> dict = new Dictionary<Test, int>();
        dict.Add(new Test() { MyProperty = 1 }, 1);
        dict.Add(new Test() { MyProperty = 2 }, 2);
        dict.Add(new Test() { MyProperty = 3 }, 3);

        // Access elements:
        var key1 = new Test() { MyProperty = 1 };
        var result1 = dict[key1];
        var key2 = new Test() { MyProperty = 2 };
        var result2 = dict[key2];
        var key3 = new Test() { MyProperty = 3 };
        var result3 = dict[key3];
        Console.WriteLine(result1 + ", " + result2 + ", " + result3);
    }
}

Output:
1, 2, 3

Live demo.
